# Выбор базы данных для ASP.NET MVC сайта

Tags: база-данных, asp.net, xmlparser, xmlhttprequest

Делаю для себя в учебных целях сайт опросник, вернее для теста, в будущем возможно это перерастет в реальное приложение если разберусь во всех этих "ваших" технологиях)
Изучаю сишарп уже 3 месяца и как никак появляются очень много вопросов насчет грамотного проектирования и преждевременной оптимизации приложения.
Вопрос лишь в том, как правильно организовать обмен данными на обычном хостинге с одной базы данных MSSQL.
На данный момент остановил выбор на XML файлах. В базе хранятся только имена авторизованных пользователей, аудентификация происходит с помощью форм. Но суть не в этом. 
Опросы могут содержать 10 и более вариантов, иногда со вложениями, или просто вопросы. 1 файл xml весит около 2 кб и это достаточно для быстрой загрузки файла при медленном соединении с помощью ajax.

И так, придумал такую схему ответа с меньшим запросом. Есть класс XmlParser с методами парсинга опросов, возвращаемый тип как текст или json, либо вернуть полный путь загрузки всего файла xml и читать с кеша пользователя, если на случай пропадет соединение. После голосования пользователя отправить ответ на сервер и удалить файл из кеша, хотя можно и оставить, это не столь важно.
Второй вариант, конечно очевиден для начинающих, это все опросы хранить в базе данных и делать запросы каждый раз при голосовании.

Хотел бы узнать, как правильно не нагружая сервер с частыми запросами организовать легкий обмен данными. А если будет 500~ пользователей и одновременные запросы на сервер + http заголовки с куками и сессией, насколько вероятно что не упадет сервер? Или за это хостинг попросит еще некоторую сумму и т.д.
Короче, я просто в растерянности

Comment: Выбор базы данных как правило редко зависит от програмиста. Чаще всего какую СУБД использует компания работодатель - под такую и пишут. У кажодой базы свои особенности и разная  цена лицензии (или отсутствие лицензии). Решение о той или иной базы принимается в зависимости от многих факторов, как минимум цена/размер субд/быстродействие СУБД. Да, однозначного ответа не существует.

Comment: @nick-n-a, в продакшене наверно так и есть, но я как программист одиночка (как же это громко прозвучало) делаю свой первый большой проект, и мало знаком с серверной обработки запросов в реальных условиях.

Answer (score 1):

- Зачем хранить файлы, если можно хранить XML прямо в базе?
- Вообще зачем нужен XML? В нем был бы смысл при экспорте/импорте
  вопросов в какие-либо другие приложения (допустим, был бы десктопный
  редактор вопросов, у вас - совместимая веб-проходилка, или приложение
  соответсвовало стандарту, вроде QTI), но в вопросе ничего об этом
  нет.

Ответ можно отправлять отдельным запросом через form data или ajax/json, пользуясь банальной автопривязкой модели. И опросы хранить в базе нативно (хоть EF, хоть ручной маппинг), если нет объективных причин делать иначе.

Comment: как вы думаете, если хранить нативно в базе, какая вероятность что сервер будет перегружен запросами от 100 пользователей в секунду? Ведь могут просто тупо тыкать по форме ежесекундно и как это может отразиться на быстродействие сервера, учитывая что в основном нагрузка ляжет на базу данных? Спасибо за развернутый ответ

Comment: @examplessss Вы решаете несуществующую проблему. Сделайте бэнчмарк, сделайте абстракцию от модели хранения, тогда и решайте проблемы по существу.

Comment: @examplessss Могу еще сказать, что коммерческие решения на этих технологиях держат около десятка тысяч пользователей в экзаменационной сессии.